# Getting 0:0 Bad option : 'varstmt' for first line in all files

Tags: node.js, jshint

I am currently working on express based nodejs backend.

I have found some of the kool stuffs like jslint , jshint and i have decided to use jshint with sublimetext3.

I was able to use .jshintrc file with options i found here http://jshint.com/docs/ but i dont why am getting this bad option `varstmt` at first line of each files

There is no issue with 'use strict'.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: You probably have `varstmt` in your config file but your `jshint` is too old to recognize that option.

Comment: Yes i do have **"varstmt" : false** should i remove it ?

Answer (score 4):

I updated jshint to the latest version, that solved the issue for me:

`npm install -g jshint`